# Como minimizar a redução de compatibiliade devido ao uso de permissões?

Tags: android, android-permission

Na minha nova versão ao colocar essas permissões no Manifest, tive uma redução de compatibilidade com vários aparelhos, teria alguma forma de verificar isso ou quem não tem suporte para essas permissões vai ficar de fora mesmo?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Acredito que a grande redução foi por causa da `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, pois nem todos os dispositivos possuem armazenamento externo, mas posso estar enganado... Poderia testar subir um apk sem essa permissão só para ver se é essa a causa do problema?

Comment: retirei e deu no mesmo, mas retirando o "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" funcionou. está permissão é por causa da lib de anúncios, e agr? :/

Comment: Não dá pra substituir o `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` por `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`?

Comment: pois é, terei que ver com o suporte do ADS.

Comment: mesmo utilizando o ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, tenho uma perda de 132 aparelhos compatíveis, o que já é melhor que antes(941) rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos motivos para esse problema é que seu app requer GPS (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), para ter acesso a localização com precisão. Ou seja, se um dispositivo não tiver GPS, ele é excluído da lista de compatibilidade.

Uma solução é usar ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, que obtém a localização pela rede. Essa forma é menos precisa, mas funciona para algumas aplicações (eu não sei se esse é o seu caso).

Outra forma é adicionar no seu `AndroidManifest.xml` o seguinte:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
```

Ou:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Isso informa que, mesmo o seu app precisando de GPS, você trata a situação para os casos em que não há. Então, os dispositivos sem GPS poderão instalar seu app.

---

Outro detalhe que limita muita compatibilidade é a versão mínima do Android (`android:minSdkVersion`) necessária para rodar o app. Se a versão mínima for muito recente, provavelmente você excluirá muitos dispostivos da lista de compatibilidade.

Por exemplo, se a versão mínima for a API 14, Android 4.0, você poderá atingir **até** 90.4% dos dispositivos.

[Referência de 12/2014.](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)